How is slope compensation implemented in the UC3843?
I was reading about slope compensation in the datasheet of UC3843 and I have watched this tutorial on youtube which gave me a general idea and overview about what slope compensation is.
Now regarding this functional diagram in the datasheet:

More specifically:

What is the function of the blue bordered part?

How did the output of the error amplifier have the -3m ramp where m is the slope as seen by current sense pin?

What is the function of the 1 mA current source at the output of the error amplifier?



See fig 8-4 of data sheet. Error amplifier is open-end. Current can be sinking/sourcing 0.5 mA, what is said. .  https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3843.pdf?ts=1720795875989&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252Fde-de%252FUC3843%253Fbm-verify%253DAAQAAAAJ_____77X3VmJ2Vg7_XC4aEiNRKMDqsKgO_HBtePqQsiJN1ghxElQTAYp0FrPpsJBRRWYQzEZFOOZbenAqEVbAaSD0yVTlb0-b5CpdNJCtGPngRZIapFeThbPhBIg749b2D9bJVVhicSr2eYxabqaU9lHYy9Y_4ZiaIq3nzRu4-7u1O0YIwUuFlE00YjTQrKOmANnhQ_kEn7EXZ29KjrVd68SUV8qKFFSlYGqlKyUsYp8Md4Ynsrp45wfHDWJDUar76gKff__NoLTssAUMXKelRv2c0LoQgJmVxoV_sevMSy-rCJY8EFEBLFoyA_aUkMKyUeX

The BJT avoids loading the oscillator circuit.  Some say that this is a noise-prone way to add slope compensation and may still load the oscillator. Tapping off a low-impedance point like the gate drive can work better: https://www.edn.com/new-slope-compensation-method-stabilizes-switchers/

I recommend an answer I gave on SE. The transistor buffers the oscillator ramp. I made another answer pertaining to slope compensation here.
